# moderntimeline — \tllabelcventry without description line

Tags: moderncv, moderntimeline

I would like to write a `\tllabelcventry` without a description line, and tried to define a new command `\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription`. I looked through the `moderncv` and `moderntimeline` command definitions to achieve this, but I am stuck, as I don't quite understand where I can hard-code such a change.

The reason I want to omit the description line is, if I don't supply a description in a `\tllabelcventry`, there is a nasty looking empty line below each entry.

Can anyone help me out here?

minimal example:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\makeatletter
\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\usepackage{moderntimeline}

\tlmaxdates{2007}{2018}
\name{name}{surname}
\title{how to omit the description line?{}} 

\newcommand{\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription}[9][color1]{%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endyear{ifthenelse(#3==0,\tl@lastyear,#3)}
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@startfraction{(#2-\tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-    \tl@firstyear)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro\tl@endfraction{(\tl@endyear-    \tl@firstyear)/(\tl@lastyear-\tl@firstyear)}%
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [#1] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear] {#4}
        rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt);
     \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@xa}{#3} \ifdim\pgf@xa=0pt
        \shade [left color=#1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \else
        \fill [#1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \fi
     }
}
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}%
}

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Section}

\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription{2008/10}{2009/9}{2008/10 -- 2009/9}{\textbf{Grade}}    {Institution}{City}{}{}

\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription{2008/10}{2009/9}{2008/10 -- 2009/9}{\textbf{Grade}}    {Institution}{City}{}{}

\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription{2008/10}{2009/9}{2008/10 -- 2009/9}{\textbf{Grade}}    {Institution}{City}{}{Description}

\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription{2008/10}{2009/9}{2008/10 -- 2009/9}{\textbf{Grade}}   {Institution}{City}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I tried to remove the description by removing `{#9}`, the code compiled, but the empty line is still there. This change should be easy to make for a trained eye, but I unfortunately don't have one.

Kind regards,
snapdeb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an definition for command `\tllabelcventry` I do not know from where you it have ...

The original definition in `moderntimeline.sty` is

```
\newcommand{\tllabelcventry}[9][color1]{%
\tl@formatendyear{#3}
\tl@formatstartyear{#2}
 \cventry{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [#1] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear] {#4}
        rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt) ;
    \ifissince
       \newdimen\fullcolorwidth
       \pgfmathsetlength\fullcolorwidth{\tl@startfraction*(1+(1-\tl@startfraction)*\tl@nsfrac)*\hintscolumnwidth}
       \shade [left color=#1,right color=#1]
(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
           rectangle (\fullcolorwidth,\tl@width);
       \shade [left color=#1] (\fullcolorwidth,0)
           rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \else
        \fill [#1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \fi
     }
}
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}%
}
```

You can change command `\cventry` to `\cventry[-\baselineskip]` to get rid of the empty line ...

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman,11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 
\usepackage[scale=0.8]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\usepackage{moderntimeline}

\tlmaxdates{2007}{2018}
\name{name}{surname}
\title{how to omit the description line?{}} 

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription}[9][color1]{%
\tl@formatendyear{#3}
\tl@formatstartyear{#2}
 \cventry[-\baselineskip]{\tikz[baseline=0pt]{ % <======================
     \fill [\tl@runningcolor] (0,0)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@runningwidth);
     \useasboundingbox (0,-1.5ex)
        rectangle (\hintscolumnwidth,1ex);
     \fill [#1] (0,0)
        ++(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0pt)
        node [tl@startyear] {#4}
        rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width-1pt) ;
    \ifissince
       \newdimen\fullcolorwidth
       \pgfmathsetlength\fullcolorwidth{\tl@startfraction*(1+(1-\tl@startfraction)*\tl@nsfrac)*\hintscolumnwidth}
       \shade [left color=#1,right color=#1]
(\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
           rectangle (\fullcolorwidth,\tl@width);
       \shade [left color=#1] (\fullcolorwidth,0)
           rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \else
        \fill [#1] (\tl@startfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,0)
            rectangle (\tl@endfraction*\hintscolumnwidth,\tl@width);
     \fi
     }
}
{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}{#9}%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{csquotes} % <===============================================
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}


\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Section}

\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription{2008/10}{2009/9}{2008/10 -- 2009/9}{\textbf{Grade}}    {Institution}{City}{}{}

\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription{2008/10}{2009/9}{2008/10 -- 2009/9}{\textbf{Grade}}    {Institution}{City}{}{}

\tllabelcventry{2008/10}{2009/9}{2008/10 -- 2009/9}{\textbf{Grade}}    {Institution}{City}{}{Description}

\tllabelcventry{2008/10}{2009/9}{2008/10 -- 2009/9}{\textbf{Grade}}   {Institution}{City}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

you can the usage of both commands `\tllabelcventry` and `\tllabelcventrywithoutdescription`:

[image]